# ANSI C quotes getting added to my code in bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, quotes, ansi-c

I am writing a script to build a CSV file to import to our LMS.  One of the script's function does an ldapsearch for the user's guid.  The command looks as such:

```
ldapsearch -x -h ldap.example.com -b ou=person,dc=example,dc=com user=username
```

On its own the command works fine.  However, in the function as part of while loop it fails.  When I set `xtrace` in bash I see the command is outputted with the following:

```
ldapsearch -x -h ldap.example.com -b ou=person,dc=example,dc=com $'user=username\r'
```

After hours of searching it seems that the `$' \r'` are known as ANSI C quotes, which I do not have a lot of experience with.  The question is, why is the argument getting wrapped with these quotes in the first place?  and second, how to I escape them?

Now, here is the kicker, this script has 3 functions which are run depending on the script's argument. `User function`, `Enrollment function` and `Course function` (no complete yet).  The issue is only happening in the `Enrollment function`, however in `User function`, the same loop is working 100% no issues, and the code is line per line identical, so what gives?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, even more if it is before I pull whats left of my hair out.

Below are the variables and affected function code:

The affected line is:

```
found=$(${ldap_cmd}=${course_instructor} | grep numEntries: | awk -F: '{print $NF}' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//')
```

This line tests to see if the user exists in LDAP or not.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set Global variables here
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
export ldap_host="ldap.example.com"
export ldap_base="ou=person,dc=example,dc=com"
export ldap_cmd="ldapsearch -x -h ${ldap_host} -b ${ldap_base} user"
export script_name=$(basename "$0"| cut -d. -f1)
export script_pid=$(pgrep "${script_name}")
export admin_id=$(whoami)
export admin_mail=$(${ldap_cmd}="${admin_id}" | grep mail: | awk -F: '{print $NF}' | tail -1 | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//')
export admin_name=$(${ldap_cmd}="${admin_id}" | grep givenName: | awk -F: '{print $NF}' | tail -1 | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//')
export admin_fname=$(${ldap_cmd}="${admin_id}" | grep cn: | awk -F: '{print $NF}' | tail -1 | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//')

function enrollment_feed () {
  # Fountion specific variables
  # enrollment_feed ${input_option} ${term_option} ${input_file}
  export input_count=$(wc -l "${input_file}" | awk '{print $1}')
  export enrollment_file="$(pwd)/erollments.csv"
  export error_file="$(pwd)/error.csv"

  # Create the output files enrollment and error
  echo "course_id,root_account,user_id,role,role_id,section_id,status,associated_user_id,limit_section_privileges" > "${enrollment_file}"
  echo "error" > "${error_file}"

  # main script while loop
  clear
  printf "\n========================================="
  printf "\n= Canvas SIS Import Builder Tool        ="
  printf "\n= Enrollment Feed                       ="
  printf "\n========================================="
  printf "\n${inf_msg} Preparing to run script ${orange}${script_name}${no_color}"
  sleep 0.5
  printf "\n${inf_msg} The script process ID is ${orange}${script_pid}${no_color}"
  sleep 0.5
  printf "\n${inf_msg} The script in run by: ${orange}${admin_fname}${no_color}"
  sleep 0.5
  printf "\n${inf_msg} The script will start running now"
  printf "\n========================================="
  printf "\n= Started $(date)  ="
  printf "\n========================================="
  printf "\n"
  sleep 0.5
  while IFS="," read -r course_title course_number course_section course_instructor; do
      if ! [[ "${course_number}" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
        printf "\r${war_msg} header or blank line detected"
        tput el
        sleep 0.5
        printf "\r${war_msg} Skipping line.."
        tput el
        sleep 0.5
        printf "\r"
        tput el
        sleep 0.5
        printf "\r${bang_mark} Line Skipped.\n"
      else
        printf "\r${inf_msg} Start processing ${orange}${input_term}-${course_number}-${course_section}${no_color}..."
        tput el
        sleep 0.5
        printf "\r${inf_msg} Searching directory services for the user record matching AndrewID ${orange}${course_instructor}${no_color}"
        tput el
        sleep 0.5
        found=$(${ldap_cmd}=${course_instructor} | grep numEntries: | awk -F: '{print $NF}' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//')
        if [[ "${found}" = "1" ]]; then
          printf "\r${inf_msg} A user record was found in directory services matching AndrewID ${orange}${course_instructor}${no_color}"
          tput el
          sleep 0.5
          printf "\r${inf_msg} Collecting all required fields from directory services matching AndrewID ${orange}${course_instructor}${no_color}"
          tput el
          sleep 0.5
          printf "\r${inf_msg} Constructing information for ${orange}${input_term}-${course_number}-${course_section}${no_color}"
          tput el
          sleep 0.5
          course_id="${input_term}-${course_number}-${course_section}"
          root_account="canvas.cmu.edu"
          user_id=$(${ldap_cmd}="${course_instructor}" | grep guid: | awk -F: '{print $NF}' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//')
          role="teacher"
          role_id="4"
          section_id=""
          status="active"
          associated_user_id=""
          limit_section_privileges=""
          printf "\r${inf_msg} Exporting all required fields for course ${orange}${input_term}-${course_number}-${course_section}${no_color} to the enrollments csv file"
          tput el
          sleep 0.5
          echo ${course_id},${root_account},${user_id},${role},${role_id},${section_id},${status},${associated_user_id},${limit_section_privileges} >> "${enrollment_file}"
          printf "\r${inf_msg} All required fields for course ${orange}${input_term}-${course_number}-${course_section}${no_color} have now been exported to the enrollment csv file"
          tput el
          sleep 0.5
          printf "\r"
          tput el
          sleep 0.5
          printf "\r${check_mark} Couse/section ${orange}${input_term}-${course_number}-${course_section}${no_color} Done.\n"
        else
          printf "\r${war_msg} The was no user record matching AndrewID ${blue}${course_instructor}${no_color} in directory services"
          tput el
          sleep 0.5
          printf "\r${war_msg} Roprting this in error csv"
          tput el
          sleep 0.5
          printf "\r"
          tput el
          sleep 0.5
          printf "\r${cross_mark} Instructor for course ${red}${input_term}-${course_number}-${course_section}${no_color} not found.\n"
          echo "${input_term}-${course_number}-${course_section}" >> "${error_file}"
        fi
      fi
  done < "${input_file}"

  printf "\n========================================="
  printf "\n= Finished $(date) ="
  printf "\n========================================="
  printf "\n"
  sleep 0.5
  # send files in email to admin
  printf "\n${inf_msg} Sending email with csv files attached to ${orange}${admin_mail}${no_color}"
  sleep 0.5
  msg_body="Dear ${admin_name},\n\nPlease find attached the following two files:\n\n - enrollments.csv: (This file contains all the Instructor information needed for and enrollments SIS import in Canvas)\n - error.csv: (This file contains course id for course with no valid instrcutor id)\n\nPlease use these files responsibly and in line with CMU privcy guidelines.\n\nBest regards,\nCanvas Admin\n\n\nThe script "${script_name}" was run by ${admin_id} from ${computer_name} at $(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T%Z")"
  printf "${msg_body}" | mailx -s "Enrollments list as of $(date)" -a "${user_file}" -a "${email_file}" -a "${error_file}" "${admin_mail}"
  printf "\n${inf_msg} Email has been sent, please check your mailbox"
  sleep 0.5
  printf "\n${inf_msg} The script has now finished processing all ${input_count} records"
  sleep 0.5
  printf "\n${inf_msg} Deleting the temp csv files"
  rm -rf "${enrollment_file}"
  sleep 0.5
  rm -rf "${error_file}"
  sleep 0.5
  printf "\n${inf_msg} The script ran for ${orange}$(ps -p "${script_pid}" -o etime | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}')${no_color}"
  sleep 0.5
  printf "\n${inf_msg} The script is now exiting"
  sleep 0.5
  printf "\n"
  printf "\n========================================="
  printf "\n= Good Bye!                             ="
  printf "\n========================================="
  printf "\n"
  exit 0
}
```

Comment: You should consider checking your script with shellcheck.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem apparently comes from this line

```
 while IFS="," read -r course_title course_number course_section course_instructor ; do
```

where you can see that `course_instructor` is read from the end of the line - and when read from a 'wrong' terminal which sends `\r` as part of the newline, the `\r` ends up in the variable. The `$'something\r'` notation is only a way how to include special characters in a bash command line.

(guessing) The other functions which work well for you probably don't use the last variable (which includes `\r`) in a place where it fails immediately.

The quick fix is a) use better terminal for data entry, b) get rid of the `\r` by eg `<<<"$var" tr -d '\r'`.

Comment: What you are saying makes sense, because the only major difference between the 2 functions are that working one has only 1 variable per line to read and IFS is not set to "," as for the terminal I am using macOS terminal, but as I mentioned above, I need the script to work in both mac and linux as it will be used by multiple admins.

Comment: Thank you for that, I was tip toeing around this for 2 days now, finally got it all working now.  I ended just doing: `teacher=$(echo "${course_instructor}" | tr -d '\r')` and replace `course_instructor` with `teacher` in the rest of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used windows or files from windows to write your script?

`\r` is a carriage return. Windows uses `\r\n` to start new lines. Linux uses just `\n`. Bash interprets `\r` as a normal character.

> the same loop is working 100% no issues, and the code is line per line identical

Are you sure, the code is identical? You cannot see the difference between `\r\n` and `\r` in a plain text editor.

Try to delte all `\r` using either

```
dos2unix -n yourScriptFile yourScriptFile2
```

or

```
tr -d '\r' < yourScriptFile > yourScriptFile2
```

Comment: I user macOS to write my scripts, but I need them to be both mac and linux compliant.